# .htaccess URL rewrite for 2 variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am having a problem with rewritting the URL using .htaccess, When the URL is something that looks like that 
original url: http://www.example.com/page.php?id=1&name=test
after rewrite: http://www.example.com/page-1-test it works fine

but the manager asked for hyphens instead of spaces so i did this

```
$name = str_replace(" ", "-", $name);
```

then i echo $page_name
http://www.example.com/page.php?id=2&name=test-some-other-text

so it would look like this http://www.example.com/page-2-test-some-other-text

in the it takes 2-test-some-other-text as the id when i try to $_GET['id'];

and here is my rewrite rule in the .htaccess

```
RewriteRule page-(.*)-(.*)$ page.php?id=$1&name=$2
```

Comment: Try `RewriteRule page-(\d+)-(.*)$ page.php?id=$1&name=$2` this is better control of groups.

Comment: `page-(.*)` will capture anything after `page-`, it won't stop at the other dash.

Comment: @Jones Your solution also worked so great thanks for your help all of you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the ID is a digit, try this rule:

```
RewriteRule page-([0-9]+)-(.*)$ page.php?id=$1&name=$2
```

It will only match digits for the ID and then end at the final dash instead of keeping on trying to greedy match.

Comment: worked as magic, thank you, you have saved me from being fired